# Problem with std::derived_from giving reference type on dereferenced iterator

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, c++20, c++-concepts

There's going to be a lot of code in this post, so I want to apologize for that right off the bat. Code that's not related to the problem and most function documentation has been removed, so feel free to ask for it if it becomes relevant.

I'm trying to make a print essentially acts as a "dispatch" to a println function, which has multiple overloads for different data types. In my code, everything is in a `cu` namespace, hence why it exists in my question. Here's some code to help understand how this system works. My problem is specific to the `cu::ptext` class when trying to print a `std::vector<cu::ptext>` object.

FILE: println.h

```cpp
// All needed includes

namespace cu
{
    template<typename Dp>
    concept DefaultPrintable = requires(std::ostream& os, Dp ln)
    {
        os << ln;
    };
}

#ifdef _WIN32

namespace cu
{
    template<typename Po>
    concept PrettyTextObject = std::derived_from<Po, console::ptext> && requires(Po text)
    {
        text.display();
    };

    template<typename Ip>
    concept IteratorPrintable = !DefaultPrintable<Ip> && requires(Ip container)
    {
        std::begin(container);
        std::end(container);
        requires DefaultPrintable<decltype(*std::begin(container))> || 
            PrettyTextObject<decltype(*std::begin(container))>;
    };
}

#endif

namespace cu
{
    template<DefaultPrintable Dp>
    void println(Dp line)
    {
        std::cout << line;
    }
}

#ifdef _WIN32

namespace cu
{
    template<PrettyTextObject Po>
    void println(const Po& pretty_text)
    {
        pretty_text.display();
    }
}

#endif

namespace cu
{
    template<IteratorPrintable Ip>
    /**
     Allows iteratiable objects with well-formed std::begin() and std::end() to
     be printed, with each element being printed on its own line. THIS FUNCTION
     SHOULD NOT BE ACCESSED DIRECTLY. Instead, use cu::print() or cu::prompt().

     @param container The container whose elements should be printed.
    */
    void println(Ip container)
    {
        // Figure out size of container
        size_t elements_ct = 0;
        for (auto el = std::begin(container); el != std::end(container); ++el)
            elements_ct++;

        if (elements_ct > 0)
        {
            using ItTy = decltype(std::begin(container));

            struct ContainerLoop { ItTy itr; size_t i; };
            for (ContainerLoop cl{ std::begin(container), 0 }; cl.itr != std::end(container); ++cl.itr)
            {
                println(*cl.itr);
                if (cl.i++ < elements_ct - 1)
                    std::cout << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace cu
{
    template<typename Ty>
    concept Printable = requires(Ty ln)
    {
        println(ln);
    };
}
```

FILE: print.h

```cpp
namespace cu
{
    /**
     Null case for print() which flushes the stream.
    */
    inline void print()
    {
        std::cout << std::flush;
    }

    template<Printable Pt, Printable... Pts>
    /**
     Prints all arguments to console on their own line. All arguments must be
     well-defined for cu::println([arg]).

     @param line   Current object to print to console
     @param others All other objects to send through recursive function call
    */
    void print(Pt line, Pts... others)
    {
        println(line);
        std::cout << '\n';

        print(std::forward<Pts>(others)...);
    }
}
```

DRIVER CODE

```cpp
cu::print("This is a test");  // <-- This line compiles fine 

std::vector<std::string> stest{ "This", "is", "test" };
cu::print(stest); // <-- Also compiles fine

cu::print(cu::ptext("This is a test")); // <-- Compiles as well

std::vector<cu::ptext> ptest{ "This", "is", "test" };
cu::print(ptest);  // <-- This line does not compile
```

To reproduce this error: https://godbolt.org/z/KroK4YehG 
(Which has the following compiler output)

```
<source>:151:1: error: no matching function for call to 'print'
cu::print(ptest);  // <-- This line does not compile
^~~~~~~~~
<source>:133:10: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with Pt = std::vector<cu::ptext>, Pts = <>]
    void print(Pt line, Pts... others)
         ^
<source>:125:14: note: because 'std::vector<cu::ptext>' does not satisfy 'Printable'
    template<Printable Pt, Printable... Pts>
             ^
<source>:111:9: note: because 'println(ln)' would be invalid: no matching function for call to 'println'
        println(ln);
        ^
<source>:120:17: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    inline void print()
                ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: its not clear what "the problem" or your question is exactly. Would help if you post a [mcve] and compiler error if there are any or explain how the code is not doing what you want it to do

Comment: I don't see where `cu::ptext` is defined in your code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This code is as minimal as I can make it, there are just a lot of parts to it. The only reason it's not reproducible is because I skipped the implementation of `cu::ptext`. If you'd like me to include that class's definition, I can do that. The issue is that the code doesn't compile. The compiler output says to "see cu::print", which isn't helpful.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I decided to skip the definition because I figured it wasn't relevant. If you'd like me to include it, just let me know, but it's quite a bit of code.

Comment: "*I decided to skip the definition because I figured it wasn't relevant.*" Hum, if it's not relevant, then why only `std::vector<cu::ptext>` doesn't work?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I think the problem lies more with the code in `println.h` since `cu::print(cu::ptext("Test"));` compiles fine. If it had to do with the class itself, I'd imagine neither of those lines would compile. I could be wrong, of course, but that was my reasoning.

Comment: this happens when I try to see the issue with the code you posted https://godbolt.org/z/d4jrc7a3T. I am not sure if any of the errors I got is related to your actual issue

Comment: for starters your `#ifdef` seems to be inconsistent. `IteratorPrintable` is only defined when `_WIN32` is defined but later you use is also when `_WIN32` is not defined

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Try this link: https://godbolt.org/z/KroK4YehG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
template<typename Ip>
concept IteratorPrintable = !DefaultPrintable<Ip> && requires(Ip container) {
  std::begin(container);
  std::end(container);
  requires DefaultPrintable<decltype(*std::begin(container))> || 
           PrettyTextObject<decltype(*std::begin(container))>;
 };
```

`decltype(*std::begin(container))` gives you a *reference* type, which makes `std::derived_from` in `PrettyTextObject` fail.

The workaround is to use `remove_reference` to remove the reference, or more simply, just use `ranges::range_value_t`, which already constrains `Ip` to be a `range`.

```
template<typename Ip>
concept IteratorPrintable = !DefaultPrintable<Ip> && 
  (DefaultPrintable<std::ranges::range_value_t<Ip>> || 
   PrettyTextObject<std::ranges::range_value_t<Ip>>);
```